# Multi region presenter in UWP with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, window, uwp, mvvmcross, uwp-xaml

I'm creating multi region presenter for UWP project. So i have created AppShell file for hamburger menu using Split View.There is AppShellFrame so every page display in this frame. But i want to display right panel for setting, so i have added second split view and set `PanePlacement="Right"` to display right side and also added another frame called as PasscodeFrame.

In second split view i designed setting view layout and added toggle button for set passcode. When toggle button toggle then i want to display PasscodeView.xaml in right side panel in PasscodeFrame. I read all about Multi region in following link :

http://depblog.weblogs.us/2015/11/23/mvvmcross-uwp-splitview/

I followed all step but passcode view open in AppShellFrame not in PasscodeFrame. I have added  the following above the class definition of the PasscodeView in code behind:

[MvxRegion("PasscodeFrame")]

I have declare app frame like this :

```
public Frame AppFrame => AppShellFrame;
```

So I think every page open in AppShellFrame. SO my question is how to open passcode view in PasscodeFrame ? I already use MvxRegion but its not working for me. And how to maintain back stack for right side panel?

Here is my code :

AppShell.xaml

```
<base:BaseView
```

```
    <!-- Top-level navigation menu + app content -->
    <SplitView x:Name="RootSplitView" DisplayMode="CompactInline" OpenPaneLength="280" IsTabStop="False">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource Background100OffWhiteBrush}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- A custom ListView to display the items in the pane.  The automation Name is set in the ContainerContentChanging event. -->

                <!-- MAIN MENU ITEMS -->
                <controls:NavMenuListView x:Name="FeedsList"

                    <!-- ACTION MENU ITEMS -->
                    <controls:NavMenuListView.Footer>

                    </controls:NavMenuListView.Footer>

                </controls:NavMenuListView>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <!-- OnNavigatingToPage we synchronize the selected item in the nav menu with the current page.
             OnNavigatedToPage we move keyboard focus to the first item on the page after it's loaded. -->
            <Frame x:Name="AppShellFrame"
               Margin="0"
               Navigating="OnNavigatingToPage" Navigated="OnNavigatedToPage"
               Background="White">
                <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <NavigationThemeTransition>
                            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                                <EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo />
                            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                        </NavigationThemeTransition>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Frame.ContentTransitions>
            </Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>

   <!-- HAMBURGER MENU -  Declared last to have it rendered above everything else, but it needs to be the first item in the tab sequence. -->
    <ToggleButton x:Name="TogglePaneButton"
        Margin="0"
        TabIndex="1" 
        Checked="{x:Bind CheckTogglePaneButtonSizeChanged}"
        Unchecked="{x:Bind CheckTogglePaneButtonSizeChanged}"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsPaneOpen, ElementName=RootSplitView, Mode=TwoWay}"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Menu" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Menu"
        Style="{StaticResource SplitViewTogglePaneButtonStyle}"/>

    <!-- Right Side Panel -->
    <SplitView PanePlacement="Right" x:Name="uiRightSideSplitView">

        <SplitView.Pane>
            <!--Setting View-->
             <ToggleSwitch Toggled="PasscodeToggleSwitch_Toggled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400" Header="passcode enabled"/>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame x:Name="PasscodeFrame" >
            </Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>               
</Grid>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class AppShell : BaseView
{     

  public AppShell()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += AppShell_Loaded;

        // AppFrame = AppShellFrame;
    }

    private void AppShell_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SettingViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
   public Frame AppFrame => AppShellFrame;
   private void PasscodeToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // Here Setting view model call passcode view model and it open in AppShellFrame. But I want to open in PasscodeFrame.

       SettingViewModel.PasscodeEnabled = true;

    }
```

}

- PasscodeView.xaml.cs

  [MvxRegion("PasscodeFrame")]

  public sealed partial class PasscodeView : BaseView

  {

  ```
  #region Constructor

  public PasscodeView()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Loaded += onLoaded;

      // Set navigation cache mode disabled, So each time create new instance of view and view model
      NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
  }
  ```

  }